# Float an element in a flex based layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to position an element below and to the right of two other sibling elements. However I have only found a solution using a float based layout.

Is there a way to make the orange box appear to the right of the red box like the example below? I need to use flexbox without setting a max-height since this is determined by the content.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
max-width: 400px;
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: lightgrey;
}

.bigbox {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.smallbox1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.smallbox2 {
width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bigbox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
  </div>
<div class="smallbox1"></div>
<div class="smallbox2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need two dimensional (row and column at the same time) layout capabilities, you're probably looking for Grids. Flexbox is one dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you're looking for. Group the small box together and set it to `flex-diretion: column`

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
max-width: 300px;
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: lightgrey;
}
.wrapper-2 {
display: flex;
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 400px;
width: 400px;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: lightgrey;
}
.column{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.bigbox {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  /*height: 100%; If you don't want the big box to take full height with flex wrap*/
}

.smallbox1,.smallbox2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.smallbox1 {
  background: green;
}

.smallbox2 {
  background: orange;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bigbox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="smallbox1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="wrapper-2">
<div class="bigbox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
  </div>
 <div class="smallbox1"></div>
 <div class="smallbox2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks K.C. this is exactly what I need. I hoped for a way without changing the HTML-markup - but then again I guess this is best-practice.

Comment: @dwigt well that is possible too if you don't want to touch the HTML at all. You can do `flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap` to the `.wrapper`, however, you'll need to set a height limit (the 2 small boxes got a 200px each) like `height: 400px;` to the wrapper

Comment: @dwigt updated the code, second one is without changing the HTML

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use css-grid over flexbox, as we are talking about a 2-dimensional layout (flexbox is great for 1-dimensional layouts).

you only need to change/add 3 lines to your code:

the wrapper needs `display:grid` and the bigbox needs `grid-column: 1` and `grid-row: 1 / 3`

I've put some extra text in my snippet, to show that this works depending on content.

check below snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 100%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.bigbox {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.smallbox1 {
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.smallbox2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bigbox">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
  </div>
  <div class="smallbox1"></div>
  <div class="smallbox2"></div>
</div>
```

I found this [css-grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) cheat-sheet very helpful,

the official [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) are here,

browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Answer (score 1):

I made with `order`

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
max-width: 300px;
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background: lightgrey;
}

.bigbox {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  order:1;
}

.smallbox1,.smallbox2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.smallbox1 {
  background: green;
  order:3;
  
}

.smallbox2 {
  background: orange;  
  order:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="bigbox">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu dui pretium, pellentesque est et, ullamcorper risus. Integer tristique aliquet ipsum, quis tincidunt augue bibendum at. Vestibulum a ultrices magna. Nullam sed massa luctus.
  </div>
<div class="smallbox1"></div>
<div class="smallbox2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the orange box to appear below the green box.

Comment: please show with picture. I don't understand what you want to.

Comment: Yes sorry it was probably confusing because I had an error in my code. I changed the wrapper max-width to allow for the orange box to also be container. K.C.'s answer is good but it would be nice if a markup change was not needed.